# firebase - check if an user is already registered in database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase app that is running on mobile devices and now I need to create the web version of it.

At the moment I have integrated firebase ui to give to users the ability to login. Since I need to show a wizard if the user isn't already registered, how I can check if user exists in the database so I can decide if show the wizard or not and then add it to the database?

Comment: "if user exists in the database" => Which database do you refer to? The users lists in the Authentication service or Firestore or the RTDB. Also what are the criteria for deciding if a user exists or not (same email? same displayName? ..)?

Comment: I want to do a check on the user email. I need to check the RTDB because the users document is stored there, but a good choice also is to check into the list of users into the authentication service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#fetchsigninmethodsforemail), which returns the list of providers with which a specified email address has previously been signed in to Firebase.

The typical flow is:

- Get the email address of the user
- Call `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` to get a list of providers
- If the list is empty, go to your account creation flow
- If the list has a single value, show the sign in screen for that provider
- If the list has multiple values, show a screen where the user can pick from those providers

Comment: I saw from the response of firebase auth providers that there is a `isNewUser` field. I'm rely on it to show the wizard, but if the suggested method is better I will switch to it

Answer (score 1):

I consider you are using firebase auth and firestore, but this is the logic

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user)=> {
            if (user == null){
              //the user is not signed in, navigate to login screen
            }else{
            //the user is signed in, try to check if he exists in the database or register him
            //let say you are using firestore roo
              let user_ = await firebase.app().auth().currentUser
              firebase.firestore().collection("collections_of_users").doc(user_.uid).get().then(snap =>{
              if(snap.exists){
              //the user exists
              }else{
                //register him, and before make sure his email is verified by checking if emailVerified === true
                firebase.firestore().collection("collections_of_users").doc(user_.uid).set({user_mail: user_.email, user_name: "xxx"})
              }
              })
    
    
    }
    
    
       });
```

Comment: Thank you, I need to test the code. I need to put it in my `App.vue` file or into the login view of my vue app??

Comment: Even both. I use to do it by checking globally if it is a authenticated user, if yes i check if he is registered in the database then if registered i make him pass, if not, i silently register him in database. I fyou want you can first redirect every unauthenicated or unregistered user to the login screen, and make all these actions from there

Comment: I can also check if the user is in the auth list of firebase?

Comment: Yes but this is possible only on the backend (firebase-admin)